# Reading Camera feed from RTSP Camera IP using Opencv's VideoCapture Function. But after sometime Python is not responding. Which cause Empty Frame

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, video-capture, rtsp

I tried various thing putting time delay and also changed the default TCP to UDP.
But after some time it start giving Empty Frame.
Please let me know if Problem is not cleared.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;udp"
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.1.2:5554/camera", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
while(1):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Frame is empty")
        break
    else:
        cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: before we start, please remove semicolon from this line.  `break;`

Comment: some modes of VideoCapture are weird in that they may intermittently have `not ret` but it'll work again in one of the next iterations. in your case, does `ret` stay False indefinitely? -- in any case, to fix the situation, close the old VideoCapture object and create a new one. I am unaware of any "reconnecting" methods on VideoCapture

Answer (score 1):

Creating new Video Capture Each Time while reading Frame OR if it did not ret then it solves the issue.
Now Program runs for longer duration without giving Empty Frame.
Thank You christoph-rackwitz Sir.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;udp"
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.1.2:5554/camera", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
while(1):
    vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.1.2:5554/camera", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Frame is empty")
        break
    else:
        cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
    vcap.release()
```